# Spark: Handling null values inside JSON Array field

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Im loading the below JSON data. Assume this is `deserialized string` from Kafka.

```
{"message":{"title": {"titleid": "111", "titlename": "AAA", "titledesc": null}, "customer": {"customerDetail": {"customerid": 1107879, "rates": [{"type": "Commission", "amount": 0.0, "currency": null}, {"type": "Total CV", "amount": 0.0, "currency": null}]}}}}
{"message":{"title": {"titleid": "222", "titlename": "BBB", "titledesc": null}, "customer": {"customerDetail": {"customerid": 1107875, "rates": [{"type": "Commission", "amount": 0.0, "currency": null}, {"type": "Total CV", "amount": 0.0, "currency": null}]}}}}
{"message":{"title": {"titleid": "333", "titlename": "CCC", "titledesc": null}, "customer": {"customerDetail": {"customerid": 1107882, "rates": [{"type": "Commission", "amount": 0.0, "currency": null}, {"type": "Total CV", "amount": 0.0, "currency": null}]}}}}
{"message":{"title": {"titleid": "444", "titlename": "DDD", "titledesc": null}, "customer": {"customerDetail": {"customerid": 1107880, "rates": [{"type": "Commission", "amount": 0.0, "currency": null}, {"type": "Total CV", "amount": 0.0, "currency": null}]}}}}
{"message":{"title": {"titleid": "555", "titlename": "EEE", "titledesc": null}, "customer": {"customerDetail": {"customerid": 1107884, "rates": [{"type": "Commission", "amount": 0.0, "currency": null}, {"type": "Total CV", "amount": 0.0, "currency": null}]}}}}


val ds = spark.read.textFile("./src/main/resources/json/JsonWithNull.txt").as[String]
ds.printSchema()
ds.show(false)

root
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)

+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"message":{"title": {"titleid": "111", "titlename": "AAA", "titledesc": null}, "customer": {"customerDetail": {"customerid": 1107879, "rates": [{"type": "Commission", "amount": 0.0, "currency": null}, {"type": "Total CV", "amount": 0.0, "currency": null}]}}}}|
|{"message":{"title": {"titleid": "222", "titlename": "BBB", "titledesc": null}, "customer": {"customerDetail": {"customerid": 1107875, "rates": [{"type": "Commission", "amount": 0.0, "currency": null}, {"type": "Total CV", "amount": 0.0, "currency": null}]}}}}|
|{"message":{"title": {"titleid": "333", "titlename": "CCC", "titledesc": null}, "customer": {"customerDetail": {"customerid": 1107882, "rates": [{"type": "Commission", "amount": 0.0, "currency": null}, {"type": "Total CV", "amount": 0.0, "currency": null}]}}}}|
|{"message":{"title": {"titleid": "444", "titlename": "DDD", "titledesc": null}, "customer": {"customerDetail": {"customerid": 1107880, "rates": [{"type": "Commission", "amount": 0.0, "currency": null}, {"type": "Total CV", "amount": 0.0, "currency": null}]}}}}|
|{"message":{"title": {"titleid": "555", "titlename": "EEE", "titledesc": null}, "customer": {"customerDetail": {"customerid": 1107884, "rates": [{"type": "Commission", "amount": 0.0, "currency": null}, {"type": "Total CV", "amount": 0.0, "currency": null}]}}}}|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Then loaded the Dataset[String] as a JSON and I see all the columns in the `schema` including `curreny` field inside the `rates` field.

```
val jsonDF = spark.read.json(ds)
jsonDF.printSchema()
jsonDF.show(false)

root
 |-- message: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- customer: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- customerDetail: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- customerid: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- rates: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- amount: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- currency: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- title: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- titledesc: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- titleid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- titlename: string (nullable = true)

+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|message                                                            |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[[[1107879, [[0.0,, Commission], [0.0,, Total CV]]]], [, 111, AAA]]|
|[[[1107875, [[0.0,, Commission], [0.0,, Total CV]]]], [, 222, BBB]]|
|[[[1107882, [[0.0,, Commission], [0.0,, Total CV]]]], [, 333, CCC]]|
|[[[1107880, [[0.0,, Commission], [0.0,, Total CV]]]], [, 444, DDD]]|
|[[[1107884, [[0.0,, Commission], [0.0,, Total CV]]]], [, 555, EEE]]|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But when I converted the `rates array column` to JSON using `to_json function` it ignored the `currency` field altogether may be because its `null`.

```
jsonDF.select(to_json(struct($"message.customer.customerDetail.rates")).as("Rates")).show(false)
```

Output:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Rates                                                                          |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"rates":[{"amount":0.0,"type":"Commission"},{"amount":0.0,"type":"Total CV"}]}|
|{"rates":[{"amount":0.0,"type":"Commission"},{"amount":0.0,"type":"Total CV"}]}|
|{"rates":[{"amount":0.0,"type":"Commission"},{"amount":0.0,"type":"Total CV"}]}|
|{"rates":[{"amount":0.0,"type":"Commission"},{"amount":0.0,"type":"Total CV"}]}|
|{"rates":[{"amount":0.0,"type":"Commission"},{"amount":0.0,"type":"Total CV"}]}|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

How do I resolve this?